# How do i insert the image in the right place?

Tags: graphics

For a board game for my pupils I want to add an icon in some of the cards that shows that they are allowed to use their calculator for that specific card (=question).

I used the package `graphicx` and I got the icon in the right size. 
The place where it appears isn't where I want it to be.

Where do I need to place the line that inserts the icon to make it in the right place? (I want the icon in the area with the red circle.)

[image]

Code sample:

```
\documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
%Voor info googelen op 'LaTeX kartei'
%a7paper: bepaalt hoe groot de fiches worden.  a6-a7-a8-a9 zijn de opties
%grid: geeft aan of er snijlijnen moeten geprint worden.  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\antwoord}[1]  {
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
#1
\end{center}

\vspace*{\fill}
}

\newcommand{\vraag}[1]{#1}

\newcommand{\kaart}[2]{
\begin{karte}[Vraag]{\vraag{#1} \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{zrm.png}  }
\answer{Antwoord}

\antwoord{#2}

\end{karte}
}

\author{M.Brouwers}

\begin{document}

\kaart{Bereken:

$2^{5}\cdot 2^{2}=$}{$2^{7}=128$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1: By `insertgraphix` do you in fact mean `graphicx`? 2: Please post a short, complete code, not just a fragment. As it stands it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: I tried to put the full code in my question but it came out really weird.. I don't know how to edit it to make it look better so i am sorry but I hope you can make something of it.

Comment: @Michelle_B: Why did you undo my edits? There were a lot of typos and wrong package name in it, that's why I corrected them. And your code is still not useful, actually :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I am so sorry, I am still getting used to this forum, the words that are used and the buttons, also my English isn't at its best.. I was trying to edit it so that I would have more code in it .. but then I saw I did something wrong because the code I pasted in wasn't written as code. When I tried to go back to the original post I might have accidently went too far back.. 

It was definately not on purpose!

I'll just try and post the 'full code again'. I know it will come out in a wrong 'lay out' but please tell me how you edit it then atleast I know what I have to do :P

Comment: To format it as code, select the code and click the `{}` button or use ctrl+k. This indents the code by 4 spaces which triggers the formatting for a code block. I also remove the curly brackets around the code, which would be incorrect.

Comment: Where can we find `kartei.cls`?

Comment: @cfr Apparently at https://github.com/kellertuer/Kartei

Comment: Are you using [Kartei-stable](https://github.com/kellertuer/Kartei/releases)?

Comment: I have no idea, i asked my mentor who introduced me to this programme and who also gave me the files. I'll update you when i know it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that I do not read Dutch and so I have no idea if this is sensible in terms of the documentation.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

---

Do you want something like this?

[image: card with image]

```
\documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
%Voor info googelen op 'LaTeX kartei'
%a7paper: bepaalt hoe groot de fiches worden.  a6-a7-a8-a9 zijn de opties
%grid: geeft aan of er snijlijnen moeten geprint worden.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\antwoord}[1]  {%
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{center}
    #1
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}%
}

\newcommand{\vraag}[1]{#1}
\newsavebox\myimage
\sbox\myimage{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a}%
}

\newcommand{\kaart}[2]{%
  \begin{karte}[Vraag]
    {\vraag{#1}}
    [\usebox\myimage]
    \answer{Antwoord}

    \antwoord{#2}

  \end{karte}%
}

\author{M.Brouwers}

\begin{document}

\kaart{%
  Bereken:

  $2^{5}\cdot 2^{2}=$}{$2^{7}=128$
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks fine @cfr. The comments relate to the documentclass options.

Comment: I more meant that I couldn't read the manual to find out if there was a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't looked at the manual yet. Actually, it's in German :-). Too late in this timezone for me to have a closer look at it. German isn't my native language

Comment: Oops. Don't know why I assumed it was Dutch. I can't read German either. But I should at least recognise that it *is* German!

Comment: Yeah i speak Dutch but the files i received were German (manual is German but some lines in the code and remarks are Dutch) this is indeed the place i want the icon to be.